# Pyspark read a JSON as a dict or struct not a dataframe/RDD

Tags: python, json, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a JSON file saved in S3 that I am trying to open/read/store/whatever as a dict or struct in PySpark. It looks something like this:

```
{
    "filename": "some_file.csv",
    "md5": "md5 hash",
    "client_id": "some uuid",
    "mappings": {
        "shipping_city": "City",
        "shipping_country": "Country",
        "shipping_zipcode": "Zip",
        "shipping_address1": "Street Line 1",
        "shipping_address2": "Street Line 2",
        "shipping_state_abbreviation": "State"
    }
}
```

And I would like to read it from S3 and store it as a dictionary or struct. When I read it like so:

```
inputJSON = "s3://bucket/file.json"
dfJSON = sqlContext.read.json(inputJSON, multiLine=True)
```

I get a dataframe that drops the mappings and looks like this:

```
+---------+-------------+----------------------------------------------------------+-------+
|client_id|filename     |mappings                                                  |md5    |
+-----------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+-------+
|some uuid|some_file.csv|[City, Country, Zip, Street Line 1, Street Line 2, State] |md5hash|
+-----------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+-------+
```

Is it possible to open the file and read it into a dictionary so I could access the Mappings or other stuff like this?:

```
jsonDict = inputFile
mappingDict = jsonDict['mappings']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve this by adding boto3 to the EMR cluster and using the following code:

```
import boto3
import json

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
obj = s3.Object('slm-transaction-incoming','All_Starbucks_Locations_in_the_US.json')
string = obj.get()['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')

json = json.loads(string)
```

Adding boto3 can be done by typing the following into the EMR Terminal:

```
sudo pip-3.6 install boto3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
inputJSON = "/tmp/some_file.json"
dfJSON = spark.read.json(inputJSON, multiLine=True)

dfJSON.printSchema()


root
 |-- client_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- filename: string (nullable = true)
 |-- mappings: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- shipping_address1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- shipping_address2: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- shipping_city: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- shipping_country: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- shipping_state_abbreviation: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- shipping_zipcode: string (nullable = true)
 |-- md5: string (nullable = true)


dict_mappings = dfJSON.select("mappings").toPandas().set_index('mappings').T.to_dict('list')

dict_mappings

{Row(shipping_address1='Street Line 1', shipping_address2='Street Line 2', shipping_city='City', shipping_country='Country', shipping_state_abbreviation='State', shipping_zipcode='Zip'): []}
```

OR (without Pandas)

```
list_map = map(lambda row: row.asDict(), dfJSON.select("mappings").collect())
dict_mappings2 = {t['mappings']: t for t in list_map}
```

Comment: Appreciate the solution but I would need to install pandas for this and that's not something I'm able to do.

Comment: Please then try the alternative without Pandas - I've just updated my answer. It might need some tuning though. Hope this helps!

Comment: Another handy way to omitt pandas is:
dfJSON.select("mappings").toPandas().set_index('mappings').toJSON().first()
then dict = json.loads(dfJSON)